# EE5 : File upload field not displaying in entry

Tags: file-uploads, fieldtype, ee5

any idea what's going wrong as the file upload field is not displaying ? CHMOD Permissions checked, PHP version 7.00 checked... But no problem to upload an image directly through File Manager [image]

Comment: You must have got some console error.

Comment: You are right, https://www.namesite.com/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&file=cp/global_end,cp/files/picker,fields/file/cp,fields/file/file_field_drag_and_drop,fields/file/concurrency_queue,fields/file/file_upload_progress_table,fields/file/drag_and_drop_upload,fields/grid/file_grid,cp/date_picker&v=1550232325 net::ERR_ABORTED 403

Comment: Share console screenshot with expanded error

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I have a similar problem with file upload fields and relationship fields not loading in the Control Panel, with the browser console displaying the following error: ```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () (index.php, line 0) https://www.domain.com/system/index.php?S=60451489f00988546e96e5578f73b2e3&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&plugin=ui.touch.punch&file=cp/global_end,cp/files/picker,fields/textarea/cp,fields/relationship/mutable_relationship,fields/relationship/relationship,fields/file/cp,fields/file/file_field_drag_and_dro